# unexpected End of File error in if else statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, end-of-life

I keep getting unexpected End of file error while running a if else statement

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -e "1: Proband\n 2: mincount\n Enter an option:"
read promin
echo $promin
if ($promin == 1) then
echo -e "Enter the proband file name\n"
read proband_file
echo "$proband_file"
endif
if ($promin == 2) then
echo -e "enter the min count number\n"
read mincount
echo "$mincount mincount"
endif
```

I tried fi instead of elseif too. But i still get the same error. Can someone help me fix that?

Comment: This looks like `csh`.  It might work if you change the shebang at the top to `#! /bin/csh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMPROVED**

The if is syntax is not correct. In the `if` there should be a program ([bash](/questions/tagged/bash) internal or external) run, which returns an exit code. If it is `0` then if is true, otherwise it is false. You can use `grep` or any other utility, like `test` or `/usr/bin/[`. But [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) has a built-in `test` and `[`.

So `[ "$var" -eq 1 ]` returns 0 if `$var` equals 1, or return 1 if `$var` not equals 1.

In your case I would suggest to use `case` instead of `if-then-elif-else-fi` notation.

```
case $x in 
1) something;;
2) other;;
*) echo "Error"; exit 1;;
easc
```

Or even use `select`. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Enter an option: "
select promin in "Proband" "mincount";do [ -n "$promin" ] && break; done
echo $promin

case "$promin" in
  Proband) read -p "Enter the proband file name: " proband_file; echo "$proband_file";;
  mincount) read -p "Enter the min count number: " mincount; echo "$mincount mincount";;
  *) echo Error; exit 1;;
esac
```

This will print the "Enter an option: " prompt and wait until a proper answer is presented (1 or 2 or ^D - to finish the input).

```
1) Proband
2) mincount
Enter an option: _
```

Then it checks the answer in the `case` part. Meanwhile `$promin` contains the string, `$REPLY` contains the entered answer. It also can be used in `case`.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you write an if-statement in bash:

**if - then - fi**

```
if [ conditional expression ]
then
    statement1
    statement2
fi
```

**if - then - else - fi**

```
If [ conditional expression ]
then
    statement1
    statement2
else
    statement3
    statement4
fi
```

**if - then - elif - else - fi**

```
If [ conditional expression1 ]
then
    statement1
    statement2
elif [ conditional expression2 ]
then
    statement3
    statement4
else
    statement5
fi
```

Example of a conditional expression:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=100
if [ $count -eq 100 ]
then
  echo "Count is 100"
fi
```

Comment: I followed the structure and now i get 
./testtest.sh: line 11: [1: command not found
./testtest.sh: line 17: [1: command not found

Comment: There are many errors in your script. See added example on howto compare integers. I.e. bash do not understand `==`. Type `help test` for a list of all the comparison operators you can use.

Comment: Note that spaces are vital!

Comment: @Vignesh: `[1: command not found` means you're missing the space between the `[` command (yes, it's a command) and its first argument, `1`. You also need spaces between operators and arguments, and before the final `]`. Also, you should almost always put variable references in double-quotes; if `$promin` is blank or contains multiple words, it'll confuse the test horribly; but `"$promin"` doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed your code and I think it works now.

I think the problem is you should **fi** instead of **endif**...

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "1: Proband\n2: mincount\nEnter an option:"
read promin
echo $promin
if [ $promin -eq "1" ]
then
    echo "Enter the proband file name\n"
    read proband_file
    echo "$proband_file"
elif [ $promin -eq "2" ]
then
    echo "enter the min count number\n"
    read mincount
    echo "$mincount mincount"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -e "1: Proband\n2: mincount\nEnter an option:"
read promin
echo $promin
if (($promin == 1)); then
echo -e "Enter the proband file name\n"
read proband_file
echo "$proband_file"
elif (($promin == 2)); then
echo -e "Enter the min count number\n"
read mincount
echo "$mincount mincount"
fi
```

I don't know if you need an if-else statement or two if statemnts. The above has an if-else.
If you need two if statements, then insert a line of code below the "echo "$proband_file"" line with the text:

```
fi
```

Then replace the line "elif (($promin == 2)); then" with the following code:

```
if (($promin == 2)); then
```